# Laravel 5 blank page

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5

I haVE my page hosted in Amazon EC2, it was working well in the root of the apache server (/var/www/html). But i want to have an other page in the same server so i start moving it to a subfolder (/var/www/html/alqip/public) so i can setup the second website in (/var/www/html/page2).

**The site is developed in Laravel 5 and it is showing a blank page without login any error in laravel logs and system logs either (syslog, apache logs, php logs).**

The permissions of storage folder are 777.

This is my **.htaccess** in public/ folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my **page.config** in /var/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName alqip.com
      ServerAlias www.alqip.com
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/alqip/public"
      <Directory "/var/www/html/alqip/public">
                    AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

I think the problem is in Laravel, not in server configuration, what do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code from a controller/route? Make sure you've used `return` keyword, for example: `return view('...');`

Comment: If your site is in /var/www/html/page1 then why is the DocumentRoot pointing to /var/www/html/alqip/public?

Answer (score 0):

Verify the firewall is down and if you are on centos check the configuration of the selinux. For default the selinux is enable edit the file `/etc/selinux/config`

> SELINUX=disabled

After disbled you have to reboot you server

Answer (score 0):

after installing Laravel you must create the .env file using the .envexample template.

the next problem you will have is permission issues

Its caused because php is running as another user by default.

so to fix this do

`sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

then edit the
`user = "put user that owns the directories" group = "put user that owns the directories"`

then:

`sudo systemctl reload php7.0-fpm`